# Upvoting a comment on a deleted Article throws an error about deleted answers

Tags: bug, status-review, comments, upvotes, articles

First tested on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/72334204/login-to-gcp-vm-instance-without-public-ip-using-identity-aware-proxy-iap) deleted article:  Upvoting a comment on a deleted article throws an error about deleted answers.

[image]

Admittedly, this isn't something people (those who know how to use the site) will see often, but if you're going to have an error for that it should be correct.

Comment: For that matter, am I even supposed to be able to see deleted articles?  I can't even see the timeline for that post or the vote split.

Comment: Who knows? I wouldn't think so, but it also wouldn't surprise me if articles remain an exception to everything

Comment: I think we should not... I can see it too, so it's likely that the privilege does not apply to them (for some reason that escapes me).

Comment: Tangential to the topic, looks like currently users can view deleted articles *if they are a member of the Collectives* (this needs confirmation if it's by-design or bug). Non-members will just see 404 as expected.