# Search brings up deleted results again

Tags: bug, search, deleted-questions

This seems to be a recurrence of a known issue:

[Some deleted posts show up in search results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400332/some-deleted-posts-show-up-in-search-results)

The advice given there is to flag for moderator attention. However, that does not seem practical, as I do not know the full extent of what needs to be changed:

I used the search [score:0 answers:0 views:..240 created:10y.. closed:yes duplicate:no](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A0+answers%3A0+views%3A..240+created%3A10y..+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano) and got this

[image: Results for searching for "score:0 answers:0 views:..240 created:10y.. closed:yes duplicate:no" 1024 items back, the first and second are deleted more than a month before, the third and fourth were migrated just about a month before]

Given that the first two results were both deleted *and* there are just over 1000 results, I do not want to check all of them but I suspect it is more than just the two. Moreover, that only covers this search, there are probably other deleted questions showing up for different search criteria.

Comment: We have a newer bug report with this as well. It's not that deleted questions show up, it's that roomba'd questions do. It's also not really "again", they never fixed it

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine "again" as in "it's happening again" not "it was fixed but showed up once more"

Comment: Yes, [bunches of previous reports](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417769).

Comment: Would be great if it was fixed, though. It's extremely annoying when deleting questions as a part of burninations

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine it's also extremely annoying when I don't even want to find deleted questions

Comment: But have y'all heard about all the cool stuff available in Collectives?!

Comment: @CodyGray like [being able to see deleted Articles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418513/upvoting-a-comment-on-a-deleted-article-throws-an-error-about-deleted-answers)?

Comment: @CodyGray Of course! I already bought 15. Can't wait!!

Comment: Narrator: It turns out that 8 out of the 15 that @Zoe bought were just poorly plagiarized copies of things she already had access to elsewhere on the Internet.